# WebClient (vert.x) with Rate Limit

Tags: webclient, quarkus, vert.x, rate-limiting, vertex

I am using the io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient in my Quarkus program  and need a rate limit on my calls.

i.e. with several calls only 2 requests may be sent in 30 seconds. Any more should then wait, possibly without running into a timeout.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Quarkus has an extension for SmallRye Fault Tolerance, which implements a simple rate limiter (see https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-fault-tolerance/6.2.6/reference/rate-limit.html). It does not implement queueing; whenever rate limit is exceeded, an exception is thrown. So if you want queueing, you'd have to implement that yourself. It is possible that the annotation-based API is not sufficient for your needs, in which case you can look at the programmatic API, which offers a lot more flexibility (see https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-fault-tolerance/6.2.6/reference/programmatic-api.html).